# The probability of getting monochromatic squares on a grid

Tags: probability

We have a grid of size $2n\times2n$. Each cell in the grid is randomly and independently colored black with probability $p$. A monochromatic square is a $2\times2$ square whose cells are all colored the same color (black or white). Let's denote with $Y$ the number of monochromatic squares in the grid after it has been colored as described in the question. I was asked to calculate $Var\left[Y\right]$ and to approximate with Chebyshev inequality the probability: $$\mathbb{P}\left( |Y-\mathbb{E}\left(Y\right)| \geq m\right)$$ for some $m \gt 0$.
My try:
We can observe that there are total $\left(2n-1\right)^{2}$ squares of size $2\times2$ in a $2n\times2n$ grid. The probability that a square is monochromatic is the sum of the probabilites that it is monochromatic black or monochromatic white. Now, each cell is colored independently of the other cells, so to get $4$ cells colored black, the probability is $p^4$ and for the white case is $\left(1-p\right)^4$. So we can define for every $1 \leq i \leq \left(2n-1\right)^2$ a random variable $X_{i}$ that indicates whether the $i$'th $2\times2$ square (strating to count the squares from left to right, up bottom) is monochromatic or not. Then $X_{i} \sim Ber\left(p^4+\left(1-p\right)^4\right)$, and $Var\left[X_{i}\right]=\left(p^4+\left(1-p\right)^4\right)\cdot \left(1-\left(p^4+\left(1-p\right)^4\right)\right)$. Because the set $\left\{ X_{i}\right\}_{i=1}^{n}$ is not independent (there can be overlapping squares) we have that: $$Var\left[Y\right]=\sum_{i=1}^{\left(2n-1\right)^2}Var\left[X_{i}\right] + \sum_{i\neq j}Cov\left[X_i,X_j\right]$$
I tried to separate the sum of the $Cov$'s by division into cases of the amount of overlapping cells of each pair of $2\times2$ squares. There can be squares $i, j$ that overlap in $0$ cells, and in that case $X_{i}, X_{j}$ are independent so $Cov\left[X_{i}, X_{j}\right]=0$, and in the other cases there can be squares that overlap in $1$ or $2$ cells ($3$ is impossible, and in the case of $4$ it is the exact same square, meaning $i=j$, and in that case $Cov\left[X_{i},X_{i}\right] = Var\left[X_{i}\right]$ and we count it in the first sum). From here on I got stuck on understanding how many pairs of $2\times2$ squares there are with $1$ or $2$ overlapping cells, and how to calculate the probability for that case, to get the rest of the $Cov$'s. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Use `\operatorname{Var}` and `\operatorname{Cov}` to get the proper font and spacing on such operators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got off to a good start.

Two squares that overlap in one square form a complex of size $3\times3$, so there are $(2n-2)^2$ such pairs.

Two squares that overlap in two squares form a complex of size $3\times2$ or $2\times3$, so there are $2(2n-2)(2n-1)$ such pairs.

The covariance, for instance in the case of overlap in one square, is

\begin{eqnarray}
\operatorname{Cov}\left[X_i,X_j\right]
&=&
E\left[X_iX_j\right]-E\left[X_i\right]E[X_j]
\\
&=&
p^7+(1-p)^7-\left(p^4+(1-p)^4\right)^2\;,
\end{eqnarray}

since for both overlapping squares to be monochromatic, they have to have the same colour, so the total of $7$ squares that they contain must all be the same colour.

Comment: Thank you very much